# Should we discourage questions about exchanges, trading, buying?

Tags: discussion, scope

On some days, Ethereum Stack Exchange feels like a help desk, and it's a lot of work to forward people to the correct peers.

1. Should we discourage questions about exchanges, trading, buying?
2. ... How? :)

It would be nice to focus more on the technical aspects of Ethereum, the smart contracts, decentralized applications, the programming languages, swarm, whisper, and everything attached.

Comment: Maybe you noticed too that, as new users are involved in Ethereum, the quantity of questions (and especially first questions) is growing fast, lets have a look at the review queue. Also many questions are about buying, selling, exchanges and basic third apps usage like MyEtherWallet. I think we all agree on the fact that it's out of this stack exchange site scope. But lets face it, newbies have to be educated as soon as possible if we don't want to be flooded by questions out of the scope. So we should probably have to deal with these questions, at least for now...

Answer (score 4):

My tuppence:

**On topic:**

Asking how things work, e.g. how does exchange X choose which orders to fulfill? Why doesn't this trading code work?

**Off topic:**

Any thing suggesting or asking for a view on valuation of something, e.g. what do you think will happen to the price of Y?

Things related to customer service, e.g. Why can't I login to Z?

Answer (score 3):

Today there was at least two questions in the review queue about withdrawal from two different exchanges and about the fact that the tx is not visible on Etherscan.
I guess they should ask the exchanges but they probably did and as we all know they don't answer, they arrived here.
But if we always answer these questions, why would the exchanges answer their support requests ? This si a evil loop...

So perhaps we could feature an answer as @danielmcclure proposed. But I don't really think people look at featured answers...

Answer (score 1):

Inviting commercial discussion is likely to cause a lot of chaos if the average ICO Slack is anything to go by. However it seems crazy to ignore the fact as it is pretty important part of the ecosystem. Perhaps there could be a featured question in the sidebar, similar to the wallet question, for "How do I acquire Ether?" that is kept up to date with the top reputable exchanges and a link to a mining guide?